# Ajax call succeeds with 200OK response but the response body is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

Trying to use a simple password-strength check service but the ajax calls though successful (200OK response) doesn't have anything in the response body (empty) and the callback which gets activated is the error-one below:

```
var password = "wefewf";
$.ajax("https://passwordutility.net/api/password/validate?password=" + encodeURIComponent(password), {
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "xml"
            })
.done(function(x) { console.log("** SUCCESS => " + x); })
.fail(function (x) { console.log("** FAILURE => " + x); })
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why would you send GET parameters when your method is POST ?

Comment: Quite simply because everything else returns 40x. For instance:
var password = "wefewf";
$.ajax("https://passwordutility.net/api/password/validate", {
                type: "POST",
data: { password: encodeURIComponent(password) },
        dataType : 'xml',
        crossDomain:true, accept: "application/xml"
            })
.done(function(x) { console.log("** SUCCESS => " + JSON.stringify(x)); })
.fail(function (x) { console.log("** FAILURE => " + JSON.stringify(x)); })

Answer (score 0):

By using the datatype parameter set to xml you've specified the response must be xml that can be parsed by jquery as per the jquery [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Since there is no xml document in the response don't use that option.

Comment: Just head over to: http://passwordutility.net/swagger/ui/index. If you try out the rest api of the website you will see that it does in fact return xml. However I fail to reproduce this using a jquery snippet. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for tuning in though.